# @import issues in IE11

Tags: css, import, fonts, icons

I'm testing a simple @import inclusion of Microsoft icons. Works fine in Chrome, but IE doesn't show anything, and I don't see any errors.

[link to example](https://jsfiddle.net/silverstarfy/gr1uuxov/)

Styling

```
@import "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css";
.ms-Icon {
font-size:35px;
display:block;
margin:10px auto;
color:red;
border:1px solid black}
```

HTML

```
<div>
<i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--alert"></i>
</div>
```

I've tried adding the css file as a reference as well in JSFiddle, and still have this issue. I know there are some issues with IE9 and below with EOTF formatting, but I'm using IE11 and haven't found any reference to a solution.

Comment: It is working for me in IE11...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, however I feel it would be best if I answered it now as I came across the same problem with IE even after all possible solutions were applied. I am assuming the website in question here was hosted on a local server, which IS the problem with IE essentially. It took me a while to realize, but I noticed that my live website had working fonts, whilst my local version didn't. By default IE usually has a setting applied to show compatibility view mode in the browser for locally hosted websites (Intranet), which means that some styling may not work correctly as intended and also imported fonts often will not work.

I can do it more effecient because I can use IF statements in templates and CSS to avoid an extra server lookup (part of my framework). Something like this:

In CSS:

```
/* #IF !$is_msie */
<load font from CDN>
/* #ENDIF */
```

In HTML:

```
<!-- #IF $is_msie -->
<load font from domain>
<!-- #ENDIF -->
```

Comment: Do you have an example? I'm not understanding how I'd test what you answered

Comment: The example you shared is working for me. Try to update you IE to latest version